# How to Create 10 Character Length Mongo ObjectId's (Like Parse Server)

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing, morphia, objectid

I'm very curious how to create the 10 char length Mongodb objectIds, i.e. (XlatDx2nYf) that Parse Server uses for its record store.

I ask specifically because trying to roll off of a Parse monolith into a more service oriented approach, in this case Java based, and can not figure out how to create objects with these seemingly 'malformed' objectIds. But this question is more generic than Java / Mongodb interface. I actually have no idea how Parse Server is getting away from creating records with these custom objectIds that do not conform to Mongodb ObjetId [standards](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/). An explanation here would be awesome.

From there I feel like I can probably figure it out in Java (Morphia) world. Thanks for your guys input!

Comment: Mongo ObjectIds are 12 bytes. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/ Can you please clarify where do you see 10 char length object id in mongo?

Comment: Parse Server creates 10 char long object ids. For reference: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#retrieving-objects objectId field populates the mongo _id filed

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like these Parse IDs are simply [Base62-encoded](https://hexdocs.pm/base62/Base62.html) integers. I found [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/jdcrensh/4670128) which can format any `int` into this format.

Unfortunately, even a Java `long` is only 8 bytes so you can't get the ObjectId in one go, but something like the following should work:

```java
ObjectId myId = new ObjectId()
String base62 = Base62.fromBase10(myId.getTimestamp()) + 
   Base62.fromBase10(myId.getMachineIdentifier()) + 
   Base62.fromBase10(myId.getProcessIdentifier()) +
   Base62.fromBase10(myId.getCounter());
```